# Host ADO.NET Data Service on Cassini

Tags: c#, .net, wcf-data-services, cassini

We need to run ADO.NET Data services without using III. I see cassini is the right option but how to host a ADO.NET Data service in Cassini.. I couldn't find any example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you want it in Cassini? You can self host an ADO.Net Data Service in a normal app, service etc. without IIS. Some details on my [blog](http://www.grumpydev.com/2009/01/10/self-hosting-adonet-data-services-astoria/) if you're interested.